# Number theory 4[7]

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Show that for all n ∈ $N^∗$, $10 ^{10^n}$= 4 [7].

I don't understand how to change $10 ^{10^n}$ into the form that we want.

Comment: Do you mean $10^{10^{n}}\equiv4\pmod7$?

Answer (score 1):

$10^n\equiv 1$ (mod 9) for any $n$, hence we can write $10^n=1+9k$ for some natural number $k$, which must be odd because $1+9k$ is even. Moreover,
$$ 10^9=10^3\cdot 10^6\equiv 10^3\equiv -1\mod 7$$
by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Therefore
$$ 10^{10^n}=10\cdot10^{9k}\equiv 10\cdot (-1)^k=-10\equiv 4\mod 7$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $10^n\equiv 4\pmod{6}$, since $10^n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $10^n\equiv 0\pmod{2}$. Thus
$$10^{10^n}\equiv 10^4\equiv 4\pmod{7}.$$